# Find the most popular attribute across all nodes with a same xpath in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, sorting, count, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

Given the example below, I would like the output to be `commonest param is: ratio`, which is the most popular name for a `parameter`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <commands>
        <commandsgroup name="FLDSMDFR">
            <command commands_type="WEATHER" name="start"/>
            <command commands_type="WEATHER" name="stop"/>
            <command commands_type="WEATHER" name="reset"/>
            <command commands_type="WEATHER" name="set_portion_size">
                <parameter  under_control="false" name="portion_size"/>
            </command>
            <command commands_type="WEATHER" name="set_meatball_ratio">
                <parameter under_control="false" name="ratio"/>
            </command>
            <command commands_type="WEATHER" name="set_desserts_ratio">
                <parameter under_control="false" name="ratio"/>
            </command>
            <command commands_type="WEATHER" name="set_precip_frequency">
                <parameter under_control="false" name="frequency"/>
            </command>
            <command commands_type="WEATHER" name="set_weather_intensity">
                <parameter under_control="false" name="weather_intensity"/>
            </command>
            <command commands_type="UI" name="use_fishing_metaphors">
                <parameter under_control="false" name="are_fishing_metaphors"/>
            </command>
            <command commands_type="UI" name="allow_spray_on_shoes">
                <parameter under_control="true" name="are_spray_on_shoes"/>
            </command>
        </commandsgroup>
    </commands>
</root>  

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <!-- stuff ... and then: -->
        <xsl:call-template name="get_commonest_param"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="parameters-by-name" match="parameter" use="@name"/>
    <!-- objective here is to find the most frequently use parameter name in all commands -->
    <xsl:template name="get_commonest_param">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/commands/commandsgroup/command[@commands_type='WEATHER']/parameter[@under_control='false'][count(. | key('parameters-by-name',@name)[1])=1]">
            <xsl:sort select="count(parameter)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                <xsl:message>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('commonest param is: ',./@name)"/>
                </xsl:message>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output seems incorrect to me. Using xsltproc (which is 1.0) in redhats I get:

```
[brent@babybrentsardines Desktop]$ xsltproc cloudy.xslt cloudy.xml
commonest param is: weather_intensity
```

FWIW: I am committed to xsl 1.0 but I'm not committed to using the Muenchane method. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *should* be committed to the Muenchian method. This consists of two parts: first, you isolate the distinct values; then you select the nodes that share the value common to each group. You omitted the 2nd part.

Consider this simplified example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="param-by-name" match="parameter" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- for each distinct name -->
    <xsl:for-each select="commands/commandsgroup/command/parameter[count(. | key('param-by-name', @name)[1])=1]">
        <!-- sort by size of group -->
        <xsl:sort select="count(key('param-by-name', @name))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <!-- output the most frequent value -->
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:message>
                <xsl:text>commonest param is: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that when you add predicates to the expression that selects the distinct values, but not to the key's match pattern, you may get incorrect results if there can be nodes that match the pattern but do not satisfy the conditions in the predicates.

Comment: Excellent, tested works. Re `discarding the Muenchian method`. I was hoping I could get a way with simply getting the most popular parameter by for eaching all the parameters in the doc and then sorting ala:

`<xsl:sort select="count(//parameters[@name=./@name]) ...etc`

My logic being, 'please return the count of all the other parameters which have the same name as this one'. I'm okay with redundant answers as all I care about is the top (descending) value in the list. However, xsl returns something about 'wrong type'

Do I have a paradigm problem here? What's the issue?

Comment: Yes, you *could* do it that way. The expression you are looking for is `<xsl:sort select="count(//parameter[@name=current()/@name])" ... />`. Not sure how efficient this is, though. I would prefer to use a key, even if it's only for the sorting part. Note that this does not return "the count of all the other parameters which have the same name as this one". It counts all parameters which have the same name as this one, including this one.

Comment: good point. Another q re `ascending` v `descending`. Does it matter? in a for-each it will have to navigate the whole list anyway right? Even if (ascending) only the first applies. Pity.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. I prefer to use ascending in the hope that the processor will indeed optimize the code - but I don't know its inner workings, and they are different for each one.